# How can i create a "run-loop" function that detects key-presses using Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python3 and I've been practicing by doing some basic programs but now I'm stuck with a little snake type game I wrote. The code I wrote so far have the following parts in order:

1. Imported modules
2. Classes to get a key from the user without the need to press "enter"
3. A function that is called by the module threading (named `move_alt()`).

```
t = threading.Thread(target=move_alt) # this is immediately after the portion of code
```

described in point 3)

4)A `move_forward()` function to create the map using a list of characters and to move a "position character" starting at the center of the map to the right till it crashes into a "wall caracter". This function is named `move_forward()`.

```
t.setDaemon(True)

t.start()

move_forward()
```

The idea is to start a thread to run simultaneously with `move_forward` function, which targets the function described in 2) to take a key from the user and depending on what key was pressed make some action over `move_forward` function, for example (and to be more specific) move_up or `move_down`, etc.

I don't know how to use the threading module correctly so I'm not getting my code to work as expected. Instead what is happening is the program would run the thread without running simultaneously the `move_forward` function and until I don't press a key (which is what it's done inside the thread) it doesn't do anything. Actually, at the beginning when i just run the program it tries to draw the map (list of characters) but only draws some characters and then gets stuck.

Sorry if my explanation wasn't efficient but English is not my first language and I tend to write too much.

P.S= I didn't put the code above because it is too long due to comments and stuff I made to learn (and not forget)

Comment: Are you sure that multithreading is necessary for this task? It seems unnecessary to me. Surely it would be better to check whether one of the buttons is pressed and execute the move_alt() function, or if not, run the default move_foward() function instead. This just seems much easier and more efficient.

Comment: Hi @CmdCoder858, thanks for the answer. Just as you said I don't necessarily think multithreading is the best option here but i saw the module and i was interested to try it to see if i could learn about that topic. You are right, your solution is much better in this case but it would be really cool if i can make the game to work using the threading module just to see it working. Anyways, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: No worries. If I were to attempt this with the multithreading module, I would probably have the main thread default to the move_foward() function only if a thread-shared variable is False, otherwise, it would check for different values of the shared variables and trigger the appropriate function. I'm not exactly sure how to implement this but it does sound like a great learning opportunity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of thinking I was finally able to make the program work as expected. First of all, the threading module wasn't the best option but for some reason I was confusing threading (which is used for concurrency purposes) with whatever I was trying to do. So after a little while I stopped using this idea.
The way I managed to make it work was actually using another module called "keyboard" (for linux users you have to use the module as root for some reason). Here is a little bit of a code to use that module:

```
  def onkeypressw(event): this function is used as a condition in the "while loop" for the move_up condition
     global stopw
     if event.name == 's' or event.name == "a" or event.name == "d":
         stopw = True
keyboard.on_press(onkeypressw)
```

---

```
def onkeypressw1(event): # this function is used as condition in the if sentence in the main function to call move_up() function

    global runw1

    if event.name == "w":

        runw1 = True
    else:
        runw1 = False
keyboard.on_press(onkeypressw1)
```

Then in the main function i have a while True loop running, where i have some if sentences that run one of four possibles move function: move_up, move_down, move_left, move_right depending of which key i pressed (w-s-d-a). Inside these "move functions" there are while loops to draw the map and move the character position(let's say the snake head) using a list of characters, until I press another button. So for example if in the main function I pressed "w" the program is going to run move_up function and move the character position until either it crashes against "the wall character" or I press "s, d or a". The conditions I put for the "while loop" are: 1)one for the wall character and 2)"not stopw" so it draws the list until I crash against the wall or stopw = True.
I know you can make this code using others modules and get the same result with less work but i wanted to use as much basic code as possible to learn python3 faster because I had previous experience programming with C.
P.S: Here is one of the moves function, just in case someone is curious:

```
def move_up():
   global c, f
   global map1
   global stopw
   while f> 0 and not stopw:
       map1[f, c] = " o " # f represents the rows and c the columns, I replaced the initial position character "_" for "o"
       f = f - 1 # up one row
       map1[f, c] = " _ " # I put the position character "_" at the new position
       cls() # clear the screen
       time.sleep(0.4) # add a little delay just to modify the snake speed
   stopw = False # reset the boolean
```

Comment: > *linux users you have to use the module as root for some reason* 
Probably because Linux has this *thing* called *security* implemented as a feature from the kernel and out. Something Microsoft "forgot" because it would take too long to get right...

Comment: @cseder Well, there are a lot of modules that won't force you to use them as root. I didn't put the whole code here but they way i did it i needed to use those variables as global. Is there another way? it would be really useful to know. What are more efficient ways of doing loops in this case? And finally, I did make the same code using other modules, for example pygame and it was much easier, but i wanted to do this using basics loop structures.

Comment: Ok, I see. Didn't mean to sound rude. It might be a worthwhile experiment to implement functionality like this yourself, but much of Python's strength lies in the vast selection of libraries of tested, efficient code ready for use. Algorithmic efficiency becomes paramount in "slow", single threaded, interpreted languages.

Comment: @cseder I didn't think you meant to be rude, on the contrary I really appreciate the advice you gave me about using the libraries that python offers to us and those made for other people who took the time to make them as efficient and organized as possible. I'm actually just starting to see how vast is the collection of resources available to use and I'm going to take your advice and make the transition to start writing code using those resources to focus on efficiency and better structure. I just wanted to make this little "project" to get used with python. Thank for the advice and time.

Comment: By all means, you're welcome! I agree to that one should definitely do some tinkering with a programming language, before using the libraries that it comes with and not to mention, all the 3rd party code available for Python. About using `global`: The easiest solution (when possible) is to simply define functions that uses arguments and returns values, instead of using `global` in your parameter-less `move_up()` function, you could pass c, f etc as arguments as an example. In larger OOP projects, *Dependency Injection* is a common cure against global state being passed around.